# How do I remove a number from the numerator of a fraction so that I am left with the variable in the denominator in this equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question is this:

$$\frac{1}{R^p} = \frac{1}{4.5\times 10^2} + \frac{1}{9.4\times 10^2}$$

I calculated the equation so that it simplifyed to:

$$\frac{1}{R^p} = 0.003286$$

But now I am stuck...

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: Oh.  I thought I should mention that the two fractions that you have do *not* simplify to $0.003286$.

Answer (score 4):

I will assume you are asking how to manipulate the equation to get the variable **out of the denominator** (the numerator is the "top" of the fraction, and the denominator is the *bottom* of the fraction):

Cross multiply, and then divide $$\frac{1}{R^p} = 0.003286 \iff 1= 0.003286\cdot R^p \iff R^p = \frac 1{0.003286}\approx 304.3$$

Comment: clean and simple works! +1

Comment: I am glad that I could see you, Amy.

Comment: Hello, @Babak! I've missed you ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Let us assume  $R\neq 0$;  you can multiply both sides by $R^p$:

$$R^p\frac{1}{R^p}=R^p 0.003286,$$

i.e.

$$1= R^p 0.003286.$$

Now, dividing both sides by $0.003286\neq 0$ you are arrive at

$$ R^p=\frac{1}{ 0.003286}.$$

Answer (score 1):

You can reciprocate both sides of the equation.  That is:
$$\frac{1}{a} = b \implies a = \frac{1}{b}$$

(assuming $b\ne 0$)

So, in your case:

$$\frac{1}{R^p} \approx 0.003286 \implies R^p\approx \frac{1}{0.003286}\approx304.3$$

EDIT:
Another approach that is sometimes helpful depending on what $p$ is equal to:

$$\frac{1}{a^b} = a^{-b}$$

So, in your case:
$$\frac{1}{R^p} = R^{-p}\approx 0.003286\implies R \approx 0.003286^{-1/p}$$

Comment: That's right! Thank you!